# Fetch date and time in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin

I have to fetch hours and minutes from time format I am getting from the system however it is showing me error like  int month= moment.Month;

DateTime productDate = DateTime.Now;

string twentyFourHourFormatHour =int.Parse(productDate.ToString("HH")).ToString();

Not picking up productdate when trying to store it in string (line 2)

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` has properties to expose all of the data you need.  There is no need to do elaborate string manipulation.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now();
int hour = date.Hour;
int minute = date.Minute;
```

Comment: I have to bind the data i.e hour and minute to my xaml page. if I write it outside the Mainpage component it is giving me error & thanx 4 d help.

Comment: This is basic C#.  There is no reason it shouldn't work anywhere in your code.  In order to bind to XAML you will need to create public properties for the Hour and Minute,